# Split with Regex creating empty strings

Tags: regex, actionscript-3, apache-flex

I'm trying to generate an array of elements that are either text or an "image block".

```
var str : String = "";

for (var i : int = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    str += (Math.random() > .5) ? "<img>amazed</img>" : "<img>happy</img>";
}

var arr : Array = str.split(/(<img>\w+<\/img>)/);
```

I want the array to have a length of 100 and for each element in the array to reflect either `<img>amazed</img>` or `<img>happy</img>`. Instead, the length is 201 and every other element is an empty String.

Is there a simple way to change the regex to avoid doubling the size of the array?

Comment: Why don't you fill the array directly? Why regex?

Comment: Because the for loop just generates a sample string for testing that'll get input by a user in the future instead of tacked together by a for loop.

Edit: Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**String.split(...)** splits the given string by the provided separator rather then searches for them.

In order to find all matches with **RegEx** you need to use **String.match(...)** method:

```
var S:String = "";

for (var i:int = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    S += (Math.random > .5)? "<img>amazed</img>": "<img>happy</img>";
}

// Pay attention to the greedy 'g' flag, if you don't set it,
// you will get the first match only as the result.
var R:RegExp = /<img>\w+<\/img>/g;
var A:Array = S.match(R);
```